# Set path to a jdbc SQLite database, where it will be located

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am using the following script to connect to a local SQLite database in Java:

```
public static Connection createOrOpenDatabase(String database) {

        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + database;

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            return conn;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

So this works pretty good and it saves it in the same directory, where also the `jar` is located. Now is my question, how can I set a absolute path, where the database is located.

For example the current location of the `db` file is:

```
C:\MyProjects\JavaFXProject\app\dist\main.db
```

Now I want to save this file to the user.home directory:

```
C:\Users\Julian\MyProjects\JavaFXProject\main.db
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I set a[n] absolute path

You can just include it as part of the connection URL, e.g.,

```
jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Julian/MyProjects/JavaFXProject/main.db
```

Answer (score 0):

first, make sub folder in src in your project and make sure you make it in your text editor - like eclipse or netbeans

this is for making sub folder in the project

[image]

then you can add your path

`Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/database/school.db");`

this is for connection code is your custom path

[image]